# Python REST API Wrapper framework?

Tags: software-development, python, framework, api, web-apis

It's not overly difficult to build a wrapper of someones RESTfull HTTP API using something like: [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) or [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org).

However, there is still a decent amount of generic boilerplate required.

Are there any decent frameworks around which reduce the amount of boilerplate required to consume 3rd-party APIs?

Answer (score 4):

So far my research has come up with:

#### [Finsh](https://github.com/jaimegildesagredo/finch)

> Asynchronous RESTful API consumer for Python. Finch is focused on remove all of the boilerplate related to consuming http based APIs and provide a high level abstraction to develop API clients.

#### [Hammock](https://github.com/kadirpekel/hammock)

> Hammock is a fun module lets you deal with rest APIs by converting them into dead simple programmatic APIs.

#### [Tortilla](https://github.com/redodo/tortilla)

> Wrapping web APIs made easy. Tortilla uses a bit of magic to wrap APIs. Whenever you get or call an attribute of a wrapper, the URL is appended by that attribute's name or method parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a good experience using CherryPy (http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/stable/tutorials.html?highlight=rest#tutorial-7-give-us-a-rest)

Also, I haven't tried it (which is what brought me to this question) but it seems like Eve might be a good option too

http://eve.readthedocs.org/en/stable